# Minimum Hardware for hadoop cluster for processing more than 1TB data evey day

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, server, bigdata

I want to create an commercial market analysis Saas platform which can handle lots of users and can process 1 Tb data  and response time should 
be near real time please suggest me the minimum hardware requirement such as 
No of nodes 
Minimum RAM and processes on each node
and also suggest me the tool set for creating this type of platform

Comment: We have no way of making such a suggestion. You need to do some experimentations and find the optimal solution for your particular job.

Comment: Can you give me example solution , your guessing for this also welcome

Answer (score 1):

Consider this image specifications as sample

[image]

Source: Hadoop operations